# Edit Privileges FAQ to mention vote down on questions free, 40 votes per day

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, privileges-page

On the [Vote Down FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) there is no mention of the recent change where down voting questions no longer result in -1 rep for the down voter.

> **What happens when I vote down?**
>
> When you vote down, you are moving
>   that content "down" so it will be seen
>   by fewer people.
>
> - Downvotes remove 2 reputation from    the post owner.
> - Downvotes remove 1 reputation from you, the voter ***<-- should mention on answers only***
> - You can vote 30 times per UTC day. ***<-- now 40***
>
> Voting down is not something we want
>   you to take lightly, so it is not
>   free.

Comment: Actually, the daily limit is not 30 votes anymore; that part should rewritten as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SLaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) did this [on the 14th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66276/10), on the [meta version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) of the page. Theoretically that gets pushed out to all the other sites periodically, but I don't know how often it happens

Comment: I believe that is on a daily basis. You refer to this change being made on the 14th, so I think they forgot to apply it network-wide...

Answer (score 2):

It has been fixed, as [the privilege page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) now reports the following text:

> **What happens when I vote down?**

When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.

> 

- Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post owner.
- Downvotes on answers remove **1** reputation from you, the voter.
- Downvotes on questions are **free**. ([Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))
- You can vote **30** times per UTC day. You get an additional **10** votes on questions only. ([Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))